# CSS What am I doing wrong? background image in unordered lists

Tags: html, css

```
.navbar {
    position:relative;
    height: 50px;
}
ul {
    height:inherit;
    position:absolute;
    top:19%;
}

ul li {
    height:inherit;
    padding: 10px 1px 10px 1px;
    display:inline;
    font-size:1.3125em; 
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

ul li:hover {
    background-color: #0E0E0E;
    background: url(img/a.svg) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 5px;


}
```

So, basically, i would like to apply an image to the highlighted unordered list items, but this image NEVER appears, how is that?

Comment: give image width and height for ul li:hover may be it works

Comment: add your hover height and width

Comment: Sure you've got the image url correct? [Works here](http://jsfiddle.net/cmhsw/)

Comment: What browser are you using, it works for me

Comment: you could try removing the background-color, as it could interfere?

Comment: @SamDenton not as its defined *before* the `background` property. It get's overwritten in this case and therefore does nothing.

Comment: I know, but it could be worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the image url incorrect. Either that or you have some other styles conflicting or your `CSS` does not correctly match your `HTML`.

See this fiddle. Using what I'd expect your `HTML` structure to be, it works fine using an external image;

**[JS FIDDLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/cmhsw/)**

If you also want the background colour to be applied as well as the picture you'd need to change your `CSS` to this;

```
ul li:hover {
    background-color: #0E0E0E;
    background-image: url(img/a.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 5px;
}
```

**[JS FIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/cmhsw/1/)**

Comment: Thank you, thats it! Works fine, my url was fine, but for some reason it didnt take it in. Fiddled with it, change the name of the file, and now it works.

The background-color i wanted to use as some form of a fallback.